# How to display special character &curvearrowleft;

Tags: html

So I am trying to display left curve arrow in my html but it only works in FF, chrome and safari but not in IE other I don't know what to search for because in new in this char encoding stuff

Comment: Post here what you are trying!

Comment: well there's a span and a character like this

`<span>&curvearrowleft;</span>`

I expect to see a curved arrow and I do in all other browsers but not in internet explorer. if I try a different special character like &amp; I get an ampersand alright.

Comment: (Older?) IE have problems with displaying characters that are not present in the used font – whereas other browsers are able to pick another font that has info on how to render that particular glyph themselves. Try putting a font that contains a glyph for this character at the end of your font stack, that usually helps. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_characters#Displaying_special_characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
  &#8630;
```

or

```
  &#x21b6;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with `&cularr;`. It works in IE 10, at least (but then again, so does `&curvearrowleft;`). Failing that, do what Stobor suggests.